# Nested ifs in reading csv, is it possible way to make it quicker?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, nested

Hey I need to get strings from column 1, but if cell cointains '-' program get value from next column (same row) and ok i did it. Works fine but is it wau to make it faster and with shorter code? I'm just curious but wanna learn something to work faster :)

```
import csv

file = 'others.csv'
reader = csv.reader(open(file, 'r', newline=''), delimiter=';')

for row in reader:
    if row[0] != '-':                               #1
        print(row[0])                               
    elif row[0] == '-':
        if row[1] != '-':
            print(row[1])         #2 nesting here
        elif row[1] == '-':
            print(row[3]) #3 nesting here
...
... 
...
```

And sample .csv

```
  col1  col2   col3   col4
0 smth1 smth   smth   smth
1 smth2 -      smth   smth
2 -     smth3  smth   smth
3 smth4 smth   smth   smth
4 -     -      -      smth5
```

table of smth :)

and the output is

```
smth1
smth2
smth3
smth4
smth5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the row until you reach a not `'-'` value by calling [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) of the filtered row:

```
for row in reader:
    val = next(x for x in row if x!='-')
    print(val)
```

You may add a default in case all the columns in the row are `'-'`:

```
...
val = next((x for x in row if x!='-'), '')
```

Comment: there is no lolumns with all rows with -, once must occur smth

Comment: can u explain me easly xD?

Comment: @MTG then you're fine without the second part

Comment: @MTG  I've added links to the answer where you can read about `next` and *generator expressions*.